# How can I default a domain to use HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking into how I can setup a static website using AWS . I purchased a placeholder domain , created a sample angular project and hosted it on www.snedz.com using AWS services like S3, cloudfront ,route 53

Then I also added SSL certificate using certificate manager in AWS. Now although https://www.snedz.com (https) is active , when I type "www.snedz.com" or "snedz.com" in my browser it seems to go to http://www.snedz.com (http)

I would expect this to go to **https:www.snedz.com**.

This is the tutorial I followed to setup this up :
https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/host-static-site-aws-s3-cloudfront/

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html

Comment: Thanks , this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just want to summarize the info given in the link posted by  John :

```
Go to cloudfront 
   >select the distribution 
     >behavior tab 
       > select behavior 
        >click edit 
         >Viewer protocol policy to:  Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
```